# problems with android studio buil comand failed

Tags: android-studio

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject -BC:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-27 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken

/Users/Janiks   oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"   is not able to compile a simple test program. 
Open File

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja.exe"

"cmTC_11230"

[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_11230.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

FAILED:

C:\Users\JANIKS~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\NDK-BU~1\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.exe

--target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain="C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64"

--sysroot="C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot" -isystem

C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi

-D__ANDROID_API__=27 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables

-fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a

-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat

-Werror=format-security -fPIE -o

CMakeFiles/cmTC_11230.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c "C:\Users\Janiks

oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"

error: no such file or directory:

'oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Call Stack (most recent call first):

CMakeLists.txt

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

See also "C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject -BC:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject.externalNativeBuild\cmake\releaseFeature\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-27 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject\build\intermediates\cmake\feature\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken

/Users/Janiks   oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"   is not able to compile a simple test program. 
Open File

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/releaseFeature/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja.exe"

"cmTC_71375"

[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_71375.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

FAILED:

C:\Users\JANIKS~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\NDK-BU~1\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.exe

--target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain="C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64"

--sysroot="C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot" -isystem

C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi

-D__ANDROID_API__=27 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables

-fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a

-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat

-Werror=format-security -fPIE -o

CMakeFiles/cmTC_71375.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c "C:\Users\Janiks

oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject.externalNativeBuild\cmake\releaseFeature\armeabi-v7a\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"

error: no such file or directory:

'oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Call Stack (most recent call first):

CMakeLists.txt

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/releaseFeature/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

See also "C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/releaseFeature/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject -BC:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debugFeature\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-27 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject\build\intermediates\cmake\feature\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken

/Users/Janiks   oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"   is not able to compile a simple test program. 
Open File

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debugFeature/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja.exe"

"cmTC_a1afd"

[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a1afd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

FAILED:

C:\Users\JANIKS~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\NDK-BU~1\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.exe

--target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain="C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64"

--sysroot="C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot" -isystem

C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi

-D__ANDROID_API__=27 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables

-fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a

-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat

-Werror=format-security -fPIE -o

CMakeFiles/cmTC_a1afd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c "C:\Users\Janiks

oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debugFeature\armeabi-v7a\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"

error: no such file or directory:

'oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Call Stack (most recent call first):

CMakeLists.txt

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debugFeature/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

See also "C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debugFeature/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject -BC:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-27 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Janiks oliveira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken

/Users/Janiks   oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"   is not able to compile a simple test program. 
Open File

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja.exe"

"cmTC_243a5"

[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_243a5.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

FAILED:

C:\Users\JANIKS~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\NDK-BU~1\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.exe

--target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain="C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64"

--sysroot="C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot" -isystem

C:/Users/Janiks

oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi

-D__ANDROID_API__=27 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables

-fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a

-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat

-Werror=format-security -fPIE -o

CMakeFiles/cmTC_243a5.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c "C:\Users\Janiks

oliveira\Desktop\androidprojects\firstproject.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"

error: no such file or directory:

'oliveira/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Call Stack (most recent call first):

CMakeLists.txt

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

See also "C:/Users/Janiks oliveira/Desktop/androidprojects/firstproject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Answer (score 1):

i believe the problem is due to the white space in one of the folder names, both for me and Janiks. Following up on my own answer, i was able to identify the problem to be a "white space issue within the a folder name". Be sure to remove any white spaces in any folder within the path pointing to the ndk sdk folder.  You can copy the entire sdk files in the sdk folder into a new directory path, which does not have any white spaces, and change the sdk directory in android studio File->Settings -> Apperance&Behavior->SystemSettings->AndroidSDK menu.
In regards to the issue from the Oliver, it seems to be the same, since he had a space in his name "Janiks oliveira".

Answer (score 0):

This error can be easily recreated in the following way.
1. install a new android studio 3.1.3, Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
2. setup a new project through File->NewProject
3. you must click "Include C++ Support", or, you will not get this error message.
4. use default settings for all other selections.
5. As it builds the example empty application, it will display the error.
6. further investigation shows that when running the clang.exe, the "ld" command failed. This is confirmed by running clang.exe in a cmd window with the following results from the commandline:

C:\Users\afellmore\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin>clang.exe -H "C:\workyh\ttt5\app" -B "C:\workaf\ttt5\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a" -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="C:\workaf\ttt5\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK="C:\Users\afellmore\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++14 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:\Users\afellmore\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\Users\afellmore\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja" -v

Android (4691093 based on r316199) clang version 6.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 183abd29fc496f55536e7d904e0abae47888fc7f) (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm 34361f192e41ed6e4e8f9aca80a4ea7e9856f327) (based on LLVM 6.0.2svn)
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Users\afellmore\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
 "ld" -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o a.exe crt2.o crtbegin.o "-LC:\Users\afellmore\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" "-LC:\Users\afellmore\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib" "-LC:\Users\afellmore\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib" "C:\workyh\ttt5\app" -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt crtend.o
clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)